# AWS EKS - CSR Pending

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, amazon-eks

I recently deploy an AWS EKS cluster with Managed nodes group. I notice when I run

```
kubectl get csr
```

All the CSRs listed are in Pending state. There are about 200 CSRs. When I try to SSH to pod it is giving "Error from server: error dialing backend: remote error: tls: internal error"

Do you guys face this issue?

Comment: Hello, it looks like you are experiencing the same behavior as described in this github issue: https://github.com/awslabs/amazon-eks-ami/issues/610